# FXML How do I have nested controllers in a single FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have read some posts that talk about nested FXML controllers in the context of FXML include files. However my problem is that I have one FXML file with multiple classes defined.

To put my problem simply. How can I do with one single FXML file the equivalent to running the makeMe() in the example below.

```
public class ClassA{
   // something
}

public class ClassB{
   public ClassA myAClass;
}

public void makeMe{
   ClassB myBClass;
   myBClass = new ClassB();
   myBClass.myAClass = new CLassA();
}
```

Comment: I'm not really clear what you want to end up with when you have loaded the FXML file (there is only one FXML, right?). Perhaps you need to restructure this using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components

Comment: Hi James D. To put the problem in more generic terms, how can I use one single FXML file to do the same thing as `ReflectTest.header = new Header(); ReflectTest.header.chartWindow = new Block();`. Maybe the problem might be clearer if i phrase it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try it if it does.

```
<Header fx:id="header" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <chartWindow>
        <Block count="4" type="Short" />
    </chartWindow>
    <measurement>
        <Block count="6" type="Short" />
    </measurement>
</Header>
```

In this situation, `Header` should look like this

```
public class Header extends Block {

    private Block chartWindow;

    private Block measurement;

    public Block getChartWindow() {
        return chartWindow;
    }

    public void setChartWindow(Block block) {
        this.chartWindow = block;
    }

    public Block getMeasurement() {
        return measurement;
    }

    public void setMeasurement(Block block) {
        this.measurement = block;
    }
}
```

So in the controller you only have a `Header` instance

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Header header;
}
```